# Understanding Forms in MVC: How can I populate the model from a List<>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

**Conclusion** in Images, can be found in the bottom

---

I'm having some trouble to get how Forms work in MVC (as I'm a WebForms Developer and really wanna start using MVC in one big project)

I took the **MVC2 Web Project** and add a simple ViewModel to it

```
namespace TestForms.Models
{
    public class myFormViewModel
    {
        public myFormViewModel() { this.Options = new List<myList>(); }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public List<myList> Options { get; set; }
    }

    public class myList
    {
        public myList() { this.Value = this.Name = ""; this.Required = false; }

        public string Name { get; set; }          
        public string Value { get; set; }      
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool Required { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Created a **Strongly Typed View**, passed a new object to the view and run it.

When I press submit, it does not return what's in the `Options` part... **how can I bind that as well**?

my view

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-11_1357.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-11_1357.png)

filling up the generated form

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-11_1353.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-11_1353.png)

when I press **Submit** the `Options` part is not passed to the Model! **What am I forgetting?**

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-11_1352.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-10-11_1352.png)

---

---

**Conclusion**

Changing the View loop to allocate the sequential number, we now have

```
<%= Html.TextBox("model.Options[" + i + "].Value", option.Value)%>
```

`model` is the name of our Model variable that we pass to the View
`Options` is the property name that is of type `List`
and then we use the property name

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your UI it seems that you did not put the data from the Options member on it.

```
<% foreach (myList obj in Model.Options) { %>
     // Add the object to your UI. they will be serialized when the form is submitted
<% } %>
```

Also check that you enclose the data in a form element

EDIT:

Sorry! I did'nt realized that you was filling the object inside the controller. Can you please show the code you have in the view?

Comment: I did, I did, or it will never show `Age` and `ZipCode` as it belongs to the object that is passed to the Index `View`... added the image of it

Comment: Ok! Have a look to this question I made here on SO some time ago. It will give you all the steps to do to make the default model binder serialize the complex object. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800305/building-a-complex-object-step-by-step-where-to-save-it`

Comment: I'm trying but I dont get it, in your example, you do not use Strongly Typed Views, you use the ViewData/Session to keep track of the values. **I tried** having `<%= Html.TextBox("Name", option.Name) %>` but I get the same, my `Options` are not populated in any way :(

Comment: @balexandre: the key is in using full qualified name for each property. If you look at the answer at some point it says: "Also each field should then have the id of ModelName.Property so that the controller knows where the property is..." followed by a code sample... If you name the property using the fully qualified name the model binder will know where to put that property...

Comment: Also, have a look at this post: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616559/default-model-binder-and-complex-types-that-include-a-list`: it uses List as in your case.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was missing :) the sequential part. Mostly appreciate for all the trouble explain it to me! to bad I can't give +5

Comment: Not want to abuse your good willing, any answer for this part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883388/dynamic-validation-on-mvc-2 ? It's this example, but now I wanted to use the internal validation for this `ZipCode` and `Age`